# Custom UserDetailsService it seems to be not autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Well I've expended quite a time figuring out what the problem with my code is. According to the trace that tomcat is sending me it has something to do with a custom `UserDetailsService` that I create for connecting Spring Security and JPA to make a login system based on data in a Database. I've read several articles so far talking about this issue but I haven't found a solution for my one. So heres the error trace:

```
 ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration.SpringSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=customUserDetailsService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration.SpringSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=customUserDetailsService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=customUserDetailsService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 24 more
```

Heres my `CustomUserDetailsService`:

```
package com.trabajotoo.saleisi.services;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import com.trabajotoo.saleisi.model.RolAsignado;
import com.trabajotoo.saleisi.model.Usuario;

@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService userService;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws 
    UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario user = userService.findByUsername(userName);
        if (user == null){
            System.out.println("User not found");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }

        return new User(user.getNomUsuario(), user.getPassword(), user.isEstado(),
                true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Usuario user){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(RolAsignado rolAsign: user.getRolesAsignados()){
            if (rolAsign.isEstado()){
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+
            rolAsign.getRol().getCodigo()));
                break;
            }
        }

        return authorities;
    }


}
```

and here is my `SprinSecurityConfig` class:

```
package com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.trabajotoo.saleisi.services.CustomSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccesHandler;



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/coordinador/**").access("hasRole('COORD')")
        .antMatchers("/director/**").access("hasRole('DIR')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll()
        .successHandler(customSuccesHandler).usernameParameter("nomUsuario")
        .passwordParameter("password");
    }

}
```

Here's my `SpringSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`:

```
package com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends 
AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

My `WebConfiguration` class:

```
package com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({HibernateConfig.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.trabajotoo.saleisi.controllers", "com.trabajotoo.saleisi.dao", 
    "com.trabajotoo.saleisi.services"})
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    // Configuracion de los archivos css,js,etc.
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    // Configuracion del manejo de las vistas
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

and My `WebAppInitializer`:

```
package com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration.RootContext;
import com.trabajotoo.saleisi.configuration.WebConfiguration;

public class ApplicationInitializer extends
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootContext.class, SpringSecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

By the way I'm using Spring Security 4.0.3 and Spring MVC 4.2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're the victim of *Application Context Hierarchies*. Your `CustomUserDetailsService` is picked up by `WebConfiguration` component scanning and defined in this context, since:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.trabajotoo.saleisi.controllers", "com.trabajotoo.saleisi.dao", 
    "com.trabajotoo.saleisi.services"})
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```

Then you're gonna inject this bean into `SpringSecurityConfig`, which is `WebConfiguration`'s parent context. Since `SpringSecurityConfig` can not access to the beans defined in its child context, it will throw a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

In order to solve this problem, you should define `CustomUserDetailsService` in root context. I'm not quite familiar with your project structure but scanning components in the service layer by `RootContext` or `SpringSecurityConfig` may fix your problem. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.trabajotoo.saleisi.services")
public class RooContext { ... }
```

Comment: Sometimes seems that the documentation isn't really helpful, thank you

Answer (score 18):

Try adding below in WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return super.userDetailsService();
}
```